# SwiftUI Tap Gesture Start / End Actions

Tags: ios, swiftui, gesture, swiftui-ontapgesture

I try to add action when a tap gesture start and end but its not work !!! and bellow the example code.

```
@State private var opacity = 1.0

var body: some View {
Image(systemName: "plus.square.on.square")
            .opacity(opacity)
            .onTapGesture {
                opacity = 0.2
            }
            .gesture(
            TapGesture()
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    opacity = 1.0
                })
            )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't *directly* answer your question, so I'm not going to leave it as an answer, but is it possible that you can achieve what you're looking for with `ButtonStyle`s? https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/advanced-swiftui-button-styling-and-animation/

Comment: What are you looking for to change opacity to 0.2 on first tap, and then set back to 1.0 on second tap? With tap gesture that makes more sense to me in your question.

Comment: No, I'm try to set the opacity to 0.2 when tap begin and set it back to 1.0 when tap end, that what I trying to do.

Comment: Why not use longPressGesture then? Use longPressGesture with minimumDuration how long you want to press, and then reset when you end.

Comment: If I use button the "ButtonStyle" will work, but I use an image and I need it to be an image, so I can't use any kind of "Style"

Comment: @TusharSharma can you show some example code for using " LongPressGesture" ?

Comment: I can’t post an answer, until that’s your requirement. You can google the same, there are multiple answers on that. Use something like--> `.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 7, pressing: { inProgress in
opacity = 0.2
}) {
opacity = 1.0
}`. Replace your gesture code with this.

Answer (score 1):

@TusharSharma is very close except for when using `onLongPressGesture` for detecting precisely the start and end of the gesture, only the `onPressingChanged` block matters.

This is a working example based on the code in question:

```swift
var body: some View {
  Image(systemName: "plus.square.on.square")
    .opacity(opacity)
    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity) {
      // Do nothing as an action, only the state change matters.
    } onPressingChanged: { starting in
      withAnimation { opacity = starting ? 0.2 : 1.0 }
    }
}
@State 
private var opacity = 1.0
```

(The `withAnimation` part is optional, but I thought you'd want it for your example.)

`minimumDuration: .infinity` "holds" opacity on 0.2 for the entire duration of time while the user holds the press.